# way to see an array MxN in a Storyboard - Swift3- Xcide 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have a project where I have a list of Students, and it's daily attendance to a class. I have been thinking create an array of (String) MxN, where M are the days of class + the name of a student, and N are the names of the Students. Inside the table, is gonna be full of 1's, 2's and 3's. 
1's means true, student assist to a class that day, 2, means false, student doens't came to class that day, and 3 for days that are inactive.

The problem here is: I can not imagine a way to "print" or "show" this data inside a storyboard.

I imagine a table like Excel could be great and the user just have to Scroll view through the table, but I dont know how to do that.
Sometimes the table is gonna be small but sometimes is gonna be big, example 10-20 students, or 30-40 students.

An scroll view can be horizontal and vertical?
Does someone have any idea or clue to do this?

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView is probably what you're looking for.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started